# regarding email form redirection

Tags: php, forms

I abc have a emailme form at php non supported website as for assumption (xyz.com) , i hosted a php file at a subdomain say (123.com) to look my website as for assumption as (abc.123.com)., its working fine , but how do i redirect from that php file at (abc.123.com) to my than-you page at xyz.com?

Any solutions? , thanks in advance and awaiting kind replies.

to be more specific

in my form i included web address as

```
urlWebsite = "abc.xyz.com"
```

and in php file i included header location as

```
Header('Location:'. $_POST['urlWebsite'].'/p/thank-you.html')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the scheme too, `http` or `https`:

```
header('Location: http://'. $_POST['urlWebsite'].'/p/thank-you.html');
die;
```

Comment: sorry guys the result after applying header('Location: http://'. $_POST['urlWebsite'].'/p/thank-you.html'); die; was undefined/p/thank-you.html

Comment: You know that you need to pass `urlWebsite` in your form with value = `abc.xyz.com` ?

Comment: hello mihai thanks for your reply my form with variable urlWebsite is located on a php non supported website , so is it possible to pass it? If yes then could you please tell m the procedure for it

Comment: ok mihai i understood your point a bit late yes i have already passed it , but the result is same i.e undefined/p/thankyou.html , any views ?

Comment: hey mihai i googled and found this header('location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); it is working fine but redirecting to abc.xyz.com , how to redirect to abc.xyz.com/p/thank-you.html , any inputs?

Comment: hey guys thanks a lot to all of you for your inputs , my problem is solved with a code and it is working like a charm the code is header('location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'p/thank-you.html');

Comment: Then you did not explain your problem properly.

Comment: hey Mihai actuaaly i am not a computer professional , so may may be due to this , i wsn't able to formulate the question in the language which other professionals can understand easily , but anyhow my problem is solved and i thank you for all your inputs regards

Comment: hey guys [code]'.$_post['variable'].' [/code]
returning empty in email why so?

Comment: i am getting the emails but some post variables are empty , in te email like this '.$_post['businessName'].' , the result in email is blank where the value of my businessName should have been displayed , guys any inputs..

Comment: but now i have one more problem hope that some one here could help me 

i am getting the emails but some post variables are empty , in te email like this[code] '.$_post['businessName'].' [/code], the result in email is blank where the value of my businessName should have been displayed , guys any inputs.

you can have a look at my php code at please have a look at my php code at[code] http://pastebin.com/uhdq9T79 [/code]

Comment: @chikitsakgupta please ask a new question. This problem is solved.

Comment: @mihia lorga thanks for your reply i undesttod your point and already asked a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319630/php-sends-empty-post-variables-in-email do you have any inputs about this? please let me solve it if you can thanks and regards